# How to access shared sharepoint files from ms teams bot activity context

Tags: sharepoint, botframework, microsoft-teams, onedrive

I want to process a file "sent" via ms teams in a personal chat with an ms teams bot app. However only uploaded files appear in the activity not "linked" files from a sharepoint folder shared with onedrive.

1. click the attachment icon, select onedrive, select a file from a shared folder to be linked:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDGc4.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW5xT.png

2. bot receives an activity with the following attachments:
   `context.activity.attachments` has the value

```json
[{contentType: 'text/html', content: '<p>test </p>'}]
```

How can I know which link the user has sent? Is there maybe another event I can listen to to know which file the user linked?

When I upload a new file instead of using one from the shared sharepoint folder then each `context.activity.attachments` contains a `content.downloadUrl` from which I can download the file just fine.

Comment: Your bot can directly send and receive files with users in the personal context, also known as personal chats, using Teams APIs. This lets you implement expense reporting, image recognition, file archival, e-signatures, and other scenarios involving direct manipulation of file content. Files shared in Teams typically appear as cards, and allow rich in-app viewing.
Ref doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-files#using-the-teams-bot-apis

Comment: sample link-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload

Comment: The sample app uses "var file = turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0];" and expects a download url in there. But for the sharepoint files there is no file there as I have stated in the OP.

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue - I think it is due to the fact that the bot framework tries to get access to the file metadata e.g. file size, but can't since the file isn't readable without authenticating which it doesn't know how to do. It does add the link (you can view it in the Files tab) but getting the attachment info fails and so just sends the message without it.

Comment: We have tried with the below sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-file-upload/csharp
Are you trying the same thing-https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/assets/93527375/01d17bd6-dec2-4dd2-98e1-b8388cda2648